# Dark line under laptop's screen

Tags: laptop, display, asus-laptop

I was curious about this small line that appears on my screen when I look at it sideways:
[image]

But it can't been seen when facing the screen directly:
[image]

It is not dirt and i scratched the area slightly and didn't feel any discontinuity. Did something happen under the screen?

Comment: Seems to be a scratch in the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little scratch in the display, you will see it when facing directly if you look really carefully when the screen is off. You can't do anything about it because it's only the top layer of the screen (the plastic probably).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know if it is concerning or if the damage will get worse with time?

Comment: No not at all, I had a worse scratch that you could see straight looking at the screen for 6 years total, it didn't get worse at all, don't worry about it !

Comment: Thank you once again! I feel the OCD kicking in and want to remove that scratch by force, haha

Comment: Resist that temptation. You can have either a tiny scratch you can see only from certain angles… or a spreading sore that gets worse each time you rub at it more. It's the equivalent of trying to remove a scratch in highly polished stainless steel… with a Brillo pad.